# Find element by Xpath using background color

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to grab an element (some date in a calendar) based on its background color. 
As you can see in this short example Sunday doesn't have a background color, but Monday does:

```
<td class="rcWeekend" title="Sunday, December 17, 2017"><a href="#">17</a></td><td title="Monday, December 18, 2017" style="background-color:#3C9770;">
```

I'm using Chrome to get an Xpath and I'm getting this:

```
//*[@id="ctl00_cphBody_rdcAvailableDates_Top"]/tbody/tr[4]/td[4]
```

I'm trying to make my path a little more robust and instead of selecting specific row and column I would just like to be able to get the very first available button with a `background-color` property.
So I tried this:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath(//*[contains(@style, 'background-color:#3C9770;')])
```

and this:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath(//*[@id="ctl00_cphBody_rdcAvailableDates_Top"]/tbody/*[contains(@style, 'background-color:#3C9770;')])
```

And some other variations of that xpath...
But I'm always getting an error. Can someone please advise how can I write this path correctly? Thank you!

Screenshot of the error:
[image]

Comment: Could you please specify the error you are getting

Comment: @AaryaHareendranath Both of them give me syntax error. I should also add that when I'm trying to use the xpath that was generated by Chrome, I'm also getting the same error. I tried to use the Chrome generated xpath like that:
`browser.find_element_by_xpath(//*[@id="ctl00_cphBody_rdcAvailableDates_Top"]/tbody/tr[4]/td[4])`
When I hover over it tells me something about unexpected tokens

Comment: As per firepath, yours is a valid xpath. COuld you please post your error here

Comment: @AaryaHareendranath I added a screenshot of the error to the original question, and you can see that I'm using xpath given me by Chrome

Comment: style="background-color:#3C9770; is succeeded to 17 text element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use quotes in xpath values

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@style, 'background-color:#3C9770;')]")
```

Comment: Thank You!!! I spent hours trying to figure out what's wrong, and I thought I tried that already! :)

Comment: glad it helps you, happy coding:)

Comment: Hey , I am unable to figure out what is the difference between what you answered and what she tried . @iamsankalp89 can you please help me

Comment: Simply the quotes are missing